# Increasing speed of float calculations at the cost of accuracy?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, floating-point

I have a program that contains large arrays of float values, and performs a lot of calculations based on them, these values are later scaled to fall between 0 and 255 to act as pixel values. Is possible to reduce the accuracy of the floating point calculations, so that it works to say, 4 significant figures, to increases the speed, and hopefully reduce the size of the array in the memory?

I am using C++, g++ to compile on linux, and boost multi arrays.

Thanks,
Angus

Comment: 0 to 255 sounds like a byte!!  just perform integer arithmetic which is faster. Possibly Faster still store as an integer and mask etc

Comment: have you considered using fixed point math?

Comment: What calculations does it perform?

Comment: Usually sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)

Comment: How do those who voted to close figure this is not a real question? The question is clear: Is there a way to do arithmetic that is faster, if less precise? The technical issues are reasonably well defined, and answering is possible and useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, modern processors do not have narrower floating-point than 32-bit arithmetic. Some have provisions for loading and storing 16-bit floating-point objects, but they convert them to 32-bit objects as they are loaded and do arithmetic with 32-bit objects. There might be some advantage to doing integer arithmetic than floating-point arithmetic, as explained below.

In much of today’s hardware, normal floating-point operations are on a par with the simplest operations in the processor. There may be some ways to speed up your arithmetic, but they may require specialized knowledge of the specific hardware you are using and considerable investment in software development.

It is not uncommon for the throughput of a processor to be the same for floating-point operations as it is for integer operations. The throughput is the number of operations per second that the processor can do. However, floating-point operations may have longer latencies. A common situation is that a processor can complete an integer addition in one processor cycle, and the processor can complete a floating-point addition in four cycles, but it does the work in four parts, and each part can work on a different addition at the same time as the other parts. So although it is four cycles from the start of a floating-point addition until it is done, the processor still completes one addition per cycle.

A consequence of this is that a chain of arithmetic such as a+b+c requires eight cycles to complete in floating-point but only two cycles in integer. In contrast, separate, unchained arithmetic, such as a+b, c+d, e+f, and g+h effectively takes the same amount of time in floating-point or integer. So, whether or not this feature would help your arithmetic depends on the specifics of your arithmetic.

Another feature that many modern processors have is called SIMD, Single Instruction Multiple Data. This feature allows the processor to execute several arithmetic operations simultaneously (often four 32-bit integer operations or four 32-bit floating-point operations, sometimes more operations with narrower integers, sometimes fewer operations with 64-bit floating-point). Accessing SIMD features with general C++ code is troublesome. Some compilers provide for some automatic use of this. Even so, it requires knowledge of and attention to specific details, such as data alignment, issues that can interfere with parallelization of operations, and informing the compiler about the specific processor models the compiled code will execute on. SIMD features can also be accessed with special compiler built-ins, macros, and/or language extensions or with assembly language.

Image processing is a popular area, and software libraries have been written that use SIMD features to provide common image processing operations, such as image scaling, image rotation, color transformation, filters such as sharpening or blurring, and others.

Since you mention Linux, and I do not work with Linux, I will leave it to others to discuss what libraries are available.

Answer (score 2):

These days, floating-point math is typically done in hardware that's designed to handle the full width of the floating-point types. Restricting it to lower precision can make it slower! That was a problem that Java ran into: originally, math on `float` types had to be done at 32 bits, and math on `double` had to be done on 64 bits. On Intel hardware this can be done, but it's much slower than running 80-bit math flat out. Because of this, he Java specification changed.